# Kernel of homomorphism $\phi:A\to Z(A)$ where $A$ is a group

Tags: group-theory, group-homomorphism

Assume $\phi:A\to Z(A)$ has its image be $Z(A)$, I'm interested in its kernel.

For any commutator $a^{-1}b^{-1}ab$,

$$\phi(a^{-1}b^{-1}ab)=\phi(a)\phi(a)^{-1}\phi(
b)\phi(b)^{-1}=I.$$

So the commutator subgroup is contained in the kernel.
Is it always the kernel? Could the kernel contain elements outside of the commutator subgroup?

Comment: One way to think about it is that the commutator captures how "far" something is from being abelian. Since the image is a commutative group you have to mod out the non-trivial elements of the commuter.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, the commutator subgroup is not always the kernel of this homomorphism  Consider, for example, $A = F_2$, the free group on two generators.  Then nothing commutes, so $Z(F_2) = \{1\}$ and thus the only homomorphism $\phi : F_2 \to Z(F_2)$ is trivial.  So, everything is in the kernel of $\phi$, which includes elements that are not commutators.

Comment: Do you know if there exist finite examples?

Comment: Yes, there do.  For example, $S_3$, the group of permutations on $3$ elements has trivial center, but any odd permutation is not a commutator.